# nested drag&drop library for Angular 13+

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

Please suggest a library which gives me Drag&Drop feature for my app written in Angular 13. Requirements:

- actively supported (I upgrade Angular ASAP)
- need to offer nested components functionality, ie. I should be able to drop something into already dropped component (container) - creating hierarchy of components
- support for typescirpt is nice-to-have

So far I've been using [ngx-dnd](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd#readme)> They've upgraded dependencies to support Angular 13 but it was quite recently ([2022-01-19](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd/commit/03a37c42e3e386b9afa86fbd3b2b73f289917fd2#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519)) and there is not much changes in a last year.

The drag-and-drop directives in [angular/cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) are great but I need nested DnD containers.

Comment: angular material has it

Comment: @The Fabio It's the **@angular/cdk** that has it, not the **@angular/material**. But this one is a no brainer, the **@angular/cdk** is the way to go here. Nested containers are also possible though you have to be the one configuring it, the supplied directives are not enough.

Comment: the **@angular/cdk** should be enought (well, we need work a bit) I can not see an example of a nested drag & drop but sure there're examples using only the @angular/cdk